# Car moving on the hill (circular motion)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

I have the following question which makes no sense to me:

> Car is moving at $20 \;\text{m/s}$ speed on the road. Curvature radius of the hill is $R = 100 \;\text{m}$. What is the maximum possible horizontal acceleration at the hill peak, if the friction coefficient is 0.3?
> [image: 1]

The car is in a circular motion where the circle is on the paper plane. From the question it seems that the car is moving at a constant speed. This means that the acceleration of this circular motion is in the direction of the radius, that is fully vertical at the hill peak. This means there is no horizontal acceleration at all. Therefore the question makes no sense to me.

The solution is given as: $1.8 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$

Comment: Consider; if the driver wished to accelerate from the 20 m/s at the top of the hill, how much acceleration would the static friction allow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the car drives over the hill, the bottom of the tires does not slip. If the car accelerates, the tires push the road backward, and the reaction force pushes the car forward. This is a question about how big can static friction be. For that, you need to know about is the normal force pushing the car onto the road.

Usually that would be the weight of the car. But this car travels in a circular path over the hill. Therefore there is a centripetal force that makes it travel in a circle. Gravity pulls the car down onto the road, and the reaction force of the road keeps the car from penetrating the surface of the road. You should be able to figure out the normal force from that.

---

Edit - More about static friction

$F = \mu N$ doesn't tell you what the static friction force is. It tells you how big it can be without the tire slipping.

Think of a car parked on a level surface. It doesn't matter if it is parked on ice or asphalt. The car doesn't move. There is no horizontal force trying to accelerate the car.

Now push the parked car. The car on ice moves because there is no friction to prevent it.

If the car is on asphalt, it does not move. The friction of the tires is just strong enough to oppose your force and keep the car from accerating. It is not stronger than your force. It does not make the car move against you.

Static friction is like other reaction forces. Gravity pushes the car onto the road. The road pushes up hard enough to prevent the car from accelerating downward and penetrating the surface.

Reaction forces often have limits to how strong they can be. A meteor digs a crater. It generates forces strong enough to break bonds and dig up the road.

Likewise, static friction has a limit. If you pushed the car with a bulldozer, it would move. The bulldozer generates a force strong enough to break the bonds that hold the tires fixed.

The formula tells you this maximum force. Friction is very complex on a microscopic level. This is not a force calculated from the nature of bonds and such. It is from many measurements of static friction with a wide variety of materials and normal forces. It doesn't always hold. For example things would change if you lubricate the road with some oil. But it is useful for learning about forces and friction. Problems can be created that make you think about them.

Comment: "This is a question about how big can static friction be." 
At the given speed and hill curvature radius the static friction is always the same **Ffr = μ6m**.  The normal force is **6m** as per calculated in the John's answer.

Comment: After the edit I now understand. The question is very poorly posed, do you agree?
It doenst mention the **static friction** nor the slipping, it mentions the **friction coefficient**, which I interpreted as a dynamic rolling friction. ------------ So the force that accelerates the car (which is rolling) is the same force that causes the car to slip? This means that the acceleration of the rolling car is related to the force that causes the slipping. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

First resolve forces vertically, to find the normal contact force $N$ in terms of the mass of the car, (the car is accelerating with $\frac{v^2}{r}$ downwards), you should get $N=6m$

The find the greatest possible friction force in terms of $m$, $F=\mu N$.  Then you can find the acceleration with $F=ma$.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. This is not the **greatest possible** friction force, it is the **actual** friction force, acting on the car with the given speed and hill curvature.

The car must apply the horizontal force equal to **μ6m** to counteract this friction, and not to decelerate. I don't see the meaning of **F=ma** in this case. If the car doesn't apply any horizontal force it will horizontally decelerate at 1.8m/s2.

Comment: @croraf When moving at constant speed the wheels are rolling and we ignore friction. (so it could continue at constant speed).  The question must mean, if the car wanted to accelerate (and tried to spin the wheels to make itself accelerate horizontally), how much could it do that, before the wheels skid.

Comment: And what is the model behind determining how much he can accelerate?

Comment: The maximum force that the engine/wheels can provide before skidding is limited by $F=\mu N$, best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the acceleration of this circular motion is in the
> direction of the radius, that is fully vertical at the hill peak. This
> means there is no horizontal acceleration at all. Therefore the
> question makes no sense to me.

As already noted in another answer, what they are asking is what would be the maximum possible horizontal acceleration at the peak of the hill should the driver attempt to accelerate the vehicle. Horizontal acceleration is only possible because of static friction between the wheels and the surface, as that is the only external force acting forward on the vehicle.

Static friction acting forward on the ground will match the horizontal force pushing back on the ground up until the maximum possible static friction force is reached. The maximum possible static friction force is coefficient of static friction times the net vertical force acting downward on the surface. That force equals the weight of the vehicle acting down minus the centrifugal force acting upward, or

$$Ma_{max}=\mu_{s}\biggl (Mg-\frac{Mv^2}{r}\biggr )$$

where $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Hard stuff. Attempting a bigger acceleration at this static friction coefficient is not possible, as the tires would start slipping, right?

Comment: @croraf That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the car and instead assume a point particle. When any particle is undergoing a uniform circular motion, it experiences an outward force which is generally given by $\frac{mv^2}{r}$.

Now we just have to apply this, along with our understanding of friction, to the above problem. The Reaction that is exerted by the road/hill on the car is the gravitational force $mg$ minus the outward force we have discussed. Now the **Maximum** force that the car needs to accelerate in the Horizontal direction, to overcome the frictional force, is merely the coefficient of friction times the reaction we have calculated above. If we take $g$ as 10 $ms^{-2}$, we would get the answer provided.

Comment: I think you are interpretting the question wrongly. This is not the **Maximum force** it is the **Minimum force** that the car needs to accelerate. Check other answers also.